# Combining geohash queries with other queries in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have used the firebase documentation for geo queries to query my database for all users within a certain radius (using geohashes), which is working well. However, I want to be able to add additional filters and do the filtering on the backend.

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
const bounds = geofire.geohashQueryBounds(center, radiusInM);
const promises = [];
for (const b of bounds) {
    const q = db
        .collection("users")
        .where("city", "==", "London")
        .orderBy("geohash")
        .startAt(b[0])
        .endAt(b[1]);

    promises.push(q.get());
}
```

However, the above code doesn't work. It works fine if I leave out the `where` part of the query. Am I doing something wrong, or is it not possible to combine these sorts of queries? Looking at the firebase documentation, it should be possible to combine an `orderBy` and a `where` query.

Comment: Did you create the necessary index for this query? If not, you should find an error message with the correct link in the log output.

Comment: I didn't have an index, but I've just tried adding the necessary composite index and it's still not working unfortunately. There wasn't an error message in the log about the lack of the index, which is a bit weird

Comment: I should also add that I get a CORS policy error when I include the ".where" part of the query, but I don't get any error when I leave out the ".where" part. Why should including the ".where" part make any difference in respect to CORS, and how can I fix this?

Comment: An error should be logged it the index is missing. It's hard to say from the code you shared though. Can you set up a minimal reproduction of the problem on a site like jsbin or stackblitz?